# The given data was invalid

Tags: php, laravel

I have added the following in my migration:

`$table->string('filePath');`

I also made sure I add it in my fillables:

`protected $fillable = ['user_id','category_id','title','description', 'filePath'];`

The field is required so I also added it in my `store` method:

```
$request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'filepath' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ]);
```

When I ran: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` I first got the following error:

`General error: 1364 Field 'filePath' doesn't have a default value`

I also ran my `testUserCanCreateAssortment` test to see what I got:

`Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: assortments.filePath`

After doing the same command again without `--seed` I got no error but just:

`table not found`

I decided the problem was with my seeders. Now I added:

`'filePath' => $this->faker->sentence(40),`

In my `assortmentFactory`.

I then started to get the following error when running `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`:

`string data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'filePath' at row 1`

I changed:

`$table->string('filePath');` to `$table->text('filePath');`

And now when I run my test I am just stuck with this:

`The given data was invalid.`

Here is my `testUserCanCreateAssortment` code:

```
        $this
            ->followingRedirects()
            ->post(route('assortments.store'), $attributes)
            ->assertSee($attributes['title'])
            ->assertSee($attributes['description'])
            ->assertSee($attributes['file_path']);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('assortments', $attributes);
```

How do I solve this?

EDIT

Now I get the following message when running my test:

`Failed asserting that [my html code]  ' contains "Corrupti consequatur deserunt non unde dolorem libero distinctio reprehenderit eius perferendis harum eum et dignissimos voluptatem similique architecto iusto expedita nesciunt omnis rerum in sequi aut molestiae tempore est in ut unde tempora omnis similique laborum laudantium aperiam quis et fuga voluptatum cupiditate sunt at rerum mollitia."`

Comment: Please follow [naming conventions](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/#section_model-properties). Model properties should be snake_case. Your column should be called ``file_path``.

Comment: Hi. I changed it to `file_path` but I still receive the same error. @mikeroq

Comment: can you post your **testUserCanCreateAssortment** code?

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze please check the new edit

Comment: @Parsa_237, could you tell me in which of $attributes keys you have the text **Corrupti consequatur deserunt non unde...** saved ?

Comment: The error is gone. It was related to my seeders. But then I got: `General error: 1364 Field 'file_path' doesn't have a default value` So I made my field `nullable`. Now I just get `the gives data was invalid` when I run my test @MarwaneEzzaze

Comment: in your form that you post, you need to set the **name="file_path"** to the input of the file so it is included in your request, that was the reason you were getting the error **General error: 1364 Field 'file_path' doesn't have a default value** .. as for the second error, I think the **->assertSee($attributes['file_path']);** triggers it since the file_path is not in the $attributes

Comment: Hi @MarwaneEzzaze. I created a file input with `name="file_path"` but I still receive the same error. I also did `file_path => null,` in my `$attributes` but that did not change anything as well. In my migration, I made `file_path` `nullable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in some environments, column names are case sensitive, so filePath is not the same as filepath.

I would suggest using lowercase for all column names.

Comment: Hi. I changed it to `file_path` but I still receive the same error.